# How to programatically find orientation of polygon?

Tags: algorithm, math, image-processing, 3d, polygon

I have the following contour (largest dark blue polygon):

[image]

This photo is taken by a smartphone and processed by OpenCV. Eventually I want to recognize the number on the bottom of this card (ignore the barcode please).

My next step would be to skew ([warp the perspective](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)) of) this image over a `3x3 transformation matrix`. Example of the expected result:

[image]

Note that the example lacks the actual image data.

**Question: How do I obtain the `3x3 transformation matrix`?**

**What I have tried in the past:**

1. replacing multiple similar line segments of the contour by a single one.
2. finding the largest 4 segments
3. assume these 4 segments form the rectangle
4. warp the image over the perspective of the rectangle

With similar I mean: line segments with nearly the same angle.

However, this does not give me accurate results. What I am hoping for is a near perfect algorithm which I can use for text recognition.

I prefer answers containing some sort of procedural language or psuedocode.

Comment: 1. I only see a single 2D-image. A polygon in 2D space has no 3D orientation.
2. every polygon fits into a rectangle
3. what segments are you talking about? what do you mean by glueing them together
4. "this does not give me accurate results": what results does it give you and what is accurate?
5. "I want a near perfect algorithm": still 8 months till christmas.
6. you have not mentioned any image-processing so far. how did you process your image so far?

Comment: with one image you can't get 3D

Comment: from one camera - you put down those lines? I dont understand -  did you mark the lines on the card - you need two cameras for 3D

Comment: @gpasch I dont want to get an 3D representation. I want a top-down representation.

Comment: so it is not sufficient to get the rotation of the card? what else do you need? provide more info please.
which text do you want to read? and why? atm I see a standard text that I would assume is known to you and a number that is encoded in the barcode anyway

Comment: @Piglet No, the angle is not top-down, so rotation alone is not enough. The perspective needs to be transformed. Also, this is just an example card, I'll have no access to a barcode on the actual card.

Comment: @Tim simply explain what you want to do. If you give some context you will help others to understand what your problem is. Something like: I want to crate a program that can read the text on a card that has been captured from an unknown perspective. the images are captured by a cell phone so I don't have any influence on the angle or the illumination....

something like that. Otherwise I see no reason why you should not simply make better pictures to get rid of all those problems

Comment: @Piglet I guess you are right. I have edited my answer: used a more exaggerated picture to show my problem, changed the description and asked a concrete question. I hope it is now more clear.

Comment: What you want is the homography matrix. It will transform your deformed rectangle/polygon into the proper rectangle.

Comment: @FiReTiTi I wish I could. The card does not have keypoints, except for the text and the number (which is unique).

Comment: @Tim: You have detected the zone with the text. You can then extract the contour, find the four main borders (Hough Transform), then find the intersection, and here you are!

Comment: @FiReTiTi Yes, thank you. This has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from the comments: compute the homography matrix.

1. You start from the polygon containing the text
2. You extract the contour
3. Hough transform to find the four sides
4. Lines intersection to find the polygon
5. Homography matrix between this polygon and the one you need.

Comment: It needed a bit of tweaking though. Hough transform detected multiple lines per side, even with a wide range parameters. So those lines needed to be identified as similar and merged together in order to get the right intersections. Anyway, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Forget about a rectangle, and just optimize for the pattern you know - pick a starting edge (any edge), walk toward the center of the image until you hit a blue line, then walk the line to find the two ends of the blue line, x1,y1 and x2,y2.  How you do this is going to depend completely on the language and representation, so any pseudo-code I provide is likely to be a waste of time.

With the two points, compute the angle of rotation - how you do this will depend on the edge you choose, but for instance, for the top line, you can use

```
angle = tangent( (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) )
```

Using the line to form a triangle with the horizontal line formed by the upper y coordinate and the vertical line formed by the right-most x coordinate.

This will give you the angle from where you want it, so you will want to rotate by `-angle` in this case (you can compute the correct angle in one operation, but its easier to visualize if you compute the angle that the image is at now.

Since you specify that the image fits within a rectangle, you don't need all of the other sides of the rectangle at all, just one.  If the image will always be somewhat vertical (and just tilted off the normal vertical axis), you can select an edge and always use that for finding that edge's line.

If the image might be rotated by 90 degrees or more, you can pick two adjacent edges (e.g. top and left), find the ends of the blue lines on each edge (they should mostly meet), and pick the longer of the two for computation, since the longer line will reduce rounding error when computing the angles.

Comment: I appreciate you answer, but it does not transform the perspective. If I would repeat your solution for all side, I would basically be performing what I already did, and it isn't really accurate enough.

Comment: You asked how to find the right perspective, so you can warp the image to the right orientation; did you mean to ask for how to warp the image itself?  Most image processing libraries include rotation as a built-in feature, so I'm confused by what you are asking.

Comment: No I mean this does not handle transforming the polygon over the perspective. It does need to rotate over the X, Y and Z axis.

Comment: @Tim your title asks for the orientation of the card. in a 2d image there is only one kind of orientation (rotation). I suggest you rewrite your question appropriately

Comment: @Piglet The card in the card has an 3D orientation, it is not really that hard.

Comment: So, to sum up, you have an image that needs to be rotated across three dimensions, but you don't have any usable reference points for the image that would do this?  I don't think your approach is going to work very well, because even if you figure out a way to rotate it correctly, your scaling algorithm is likely to screw with the barcode itself.  Instead, you might have better luck creating a text/barcode decoder that can compensate for skewed images, or find OCR software that works with the skew.

Comment: @MattJordan Yes that is correctly. But I can create reference points for the target perspective. I'm not sure how to go from there.